# Mixing CocoaPods with Swift package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have an `iOS` project, that is divided into various `frameworks` using `Swift packages`. Now I need to create another `swift package`, which would include:

- Some dependencies from other `swift packages`
- Other dependencies from `CocoaPods` (`GoogleMLKit/ObjectDetectionCustom` to be exact)

How can I do this? Is there some way to import `cocoa pod` into the `swift package`?
For now, I implemented all this new functionality inside the main `iOS app project`, but I really don't like this solution. I would love to have this in a separate package.

Comment: Did you find solution of using Cocoapods in swift package manager?

Comment: I would love an answer to this too, im in this exact situation where I want to create a package but that lib uses MLKit, and it only ships from cocoa pods

Comment: I'm on the same path. Have anyone sorted out how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You could perhaps include the GoogleMLKit/ObjectDetectionCustom package (if there is one) inside the package you are importing into your main project

For example I use Reachability package inside my own package which I then include in my main project

Comment: This question actually assumes that there is no package available, even if there are some available now. But the essence of this question was about mixing it with cocoa pods. If there is swift package, then there is no problem